# How to get static particles centered on vertices?

Tags: particles, hair

I am trying to get particles to render at the center of vertices in blender 2.81.

So far, I am trying to use the hair particles with the source emitting from vertices. It seems to work but I noticed quite a big **gap** between the supposed vertice and some particles as shown in the image.
[image]

I was wondering if there is a setting that I missed or if there is another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the *Properties Window > Particle Settings* tab make sure your *Particle Physics* are off by changing from *Newtonian* to *None*, if you don't need them.

If are planning on animating them, or require physics try turning down the *Initial Velocity* parameter.

Also make sure you *Particle Modifier* is right after the base mesh, not after any other constructive modifiers.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your super quick answer I was desesperately searching for the last part!! I did not know about the order of modifier here to be that important. Marking as solved.

Comment: Hi @Duarte I am curious what tool you used to record the actions. For my own future answers it may be easier at times to demo than word smith it up.

Comment: I use [Second Option](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/964#964), choose whichever suits you best.

Comment: "*it may be easier at times to demo than word smith it up*" While images are helpful and encouraged, [thoroughly explain the issue too, don't just post an animation](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)